# i just get a big X on my image not on the road marking

Tags: python, opencv

before it would show me the lines but when I tried to make the lines blue and add them to the image I just get a massive blue X on my image?

I've rewritten the code again and even found a tutorial but still no luck, still get the same issue

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def make_coordinates (image, line_parameters):
    slope, incercept = line_parameters
    y1 = image.shape[0]
    y2 = int(y1*(3/5))
    x1 = int((y1 - incercept)/slope)
    x2 = int((y2 - incercept)/slope)
    return np.array([x1, y1, x2, y2])

def average_slope_intercept(image, lines):
    left_fit = []
    right_fit = []
    for line in lines:
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = line.reshape(4)
        parameters = np.polyfit((x1, x2), (y1, y2), 1)
        slope = parameters[0]
        intercept = parameters[1]
        if slope < 0:
            left_fit.append((slope, intercept))
        else:
            right_fit.append((slope, intercept))
    left_fit_average = np.average(left_fit, axis = 0)
    right_fit_average = np.average(right_fit, axis = 0)
    left_line = make_coordinates(image, left_fit_average)
    right_line = make_coordinates(image, right_fit_average)
    return np.array([left_line, right_line])


def canny(image):
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5),0)
    canny = cv2.Canny(blur, 50, 150)
    return canny

def display_lines(image, lines):
    line_image = np.zeros_like(image)
    if lines is not None:
        for line in lines:
            x1, y1, x2, y2 = line.reshape(4)
            cv2.line(line_image, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (255, 0, 0), 10)
    return line_image

def region_of_interest(image):
    height = image.shape[0]
    polygons = np.array([
    [(200, height), (1100, height), (550, 250)]
    ])
    mask = np.zeros_like(image)
    cv2.fillPoly(mask, polygons, 255)
    masked_images = cv2.bitwise_and(image, mask)
    return masked_images

image = cv2.imread('test_image.jpg')
lane_image = np.copy(image)
canny_image = canny(lane_image)
cropped_image = region_of_interest(canny_image)
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(cropped_image, 2, np.pi/180, 100, np.array([]), minLineLength=40, maxLineGap=5)
averaged_lines = average_slope_intercept(lane_image, lines)
line_image = display_lines(lane_image, averaged_lines)
combo_image = cv2.addWeighted(lane_image, 0.8, line_image, 1, 1)
cv2.imshow("results", line_image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

i don't​ get any errors on my terminal window

Comment: The question is not clear. Please provide a test image sample. Also provide what is the desired result. Are you trying to draw two lanes until the vanishing point? For example, [Link](https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1200/1*pfxGznSFX8BFc1KdomPbCw.png). If it's the case, simply calculate the point of intersection between the two lines and clip the line rendering above the point of intersection.

Answer (score 0):

its suppose to draw lines half way up the picture not like the picture below.

This is what i get when im trying to add lines to the road

[image]

Comment: You should edit this information into the original question.